# How can I embed private dailymotion live stream on the website?

Tags: dailymotion-api

I want to embed the private live stream of dailymotion to my website, and only member on my site can see the live stream. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the embed code directly with the API by using the "embed_url" field ([Documentation](https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#video-embed_url-field)).

Ex: `https://api.dailymotion.com/video/{your_stream _id}?fields=embed_url.`

You can also get this code through the interfaces in your partner space:
[image]

or directly in the stream page:
[image]

Then you have to manage the access to the page on your website where you embed the player