# Is there a way to share private DailyMotion videos?

Tags: dailymotion-api

I know basically nothing about coding but need a way to share private videos without making them public (the videos are shared with my research team only for the purposes of our project). I need to embed videos into my survey and I've come across a few different threads discussing this in heavy coding language (for me) that I can't wrap my head around.

I understand that I need to request the private id in order to embed the link (and yes, I understand that this inevitably lessens the private state of the video, but I've accepted that I can only control for so much) into the study, but I have no clue how to do this. The DailyMotion API pages are no easier for me to digest, and I would be very grateful if someone can explain in layman's terms how to walk these steps?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the share link or the embed code of your video by using the share button on our platform as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53745149/3668925

Using the API you can get those information by asking for the fields `embed_html` and `url`

Example: https://api.dailymotion.com/video/k123example?fields=id,private_id,title,embed_html,url

Response:

```
{
  "title": "video example",
  "embed_html": "<iframe frameborder=\"0\" width=\"480\" height=\"270\" src=\"https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/k123example\" allowfullscreen allow=\"autoplay\"></iframe>",
  "url": "https://www.dailymotion.com/video/k123example"
}
```